# Входная строка имела неверный формат. на каждый радиобатон и первый батон выдает эту ошибку

Tags: c#, формат, zedgraph

```
   private void zedGraphControl1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MasterPane myMaster = zdc.MasterPane;
        // очистка 
        myMaster.PaneList.Clear();
        // надпись сверху
        myMaster.Title.Text = " laba 2";
        myMaster.Title.IsVisible = true;
        myMaster.Title.FontSpec.Size = 50;
        // установка фона
        myMaster.Fill = new Fill(Color.White, Color.MediumSlateBlue, 45.0F);
        // размер  надписи
        myMaster.BaseDimension = 20;
        //расстояние по вертикали и/или горизонтали
        myMaster.Margin.All = 10;
        // чтобы легенда не отображалась 
        myMaster.Legend.IsVisible = false;
        myMaster.Legend.Position = LegendPos.TopCenter;
        // инициализация объекта 
        ColorSymbolRotator rotator = new ColorSymbolRotator();
        // установка параметров объекта 
        GraphPane myPane = new GraphPane(new Rectangle(5, 30, Width - 500, Height - 200), null, "", "");
        // заливка графика 
        myPane.Fill = new Fill(Color.White, Color.Red, 45.0F);
        // хранилище данных 
        PointPairList listData = new PointPairList();
        // линия  на графике 
        LineItem DataCurvePop = new LineItem("");
        myPane.AddCurve("данные", listData, Color.Red, rotator.NextSymbol);
        DataCurvePop.Symbol.Fill = new Fill(Color.White);
        // добавление 
        myMaster.Add(myPane);
        zdc.AxisChange();
        zdc.Invalidate();

    }

    private void X_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MasterPane myMaster = zdc.MasterPane;
        ColorSymbolRotator rotator = new ColorSymbolRotator();
        PointPairList listData = new PointPairList();
        GraphPane myPane = new GraphPane(new Rectangle(5, 30, Width - 400, Height - 270), null, "Z", "f");
        myPane.Fill = new Fill(Color.White, Color.Red, 45.0F);
        double X = double.Parse(textBox1.Text);
        double Y = double.Parse(textBox2.Text);
        for (Int32 z = 0; z < 100; z++)
        {
            listData.Add(z, Math.Log(Math.Pow(Y, -Math.Sqrt(Math.Abs(X)))) * (X - Y / 2) + Math.Pow(Math.Sin(Math.Atan(z)), 2));
        }
        LineItem DataCurvePop = new LineItem("");
        myPane.AddCurve("данные", listData, Color.Red, rotator.NextSymbol);
        DataCurvePop.Symbol.Fill = new Fill(Color.White);

        myMaster.Add(myPane);
        zdc.AxisChange();
        zdc.Invalidate();
        GraphPane pane = zdc.GraphPane;
        pane.YAxis.Title.Text = "f";
        pane.XAxis.Title.Text = "x";

    }

    private void Y_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MasterPane myMaster = zdc.MasterPane;
        ColorSymbolRotator rotator = new ColorSymbolRotator();
        PointPairList listData = new PointPairList();
        GraphPane myPane = new GraphPane(new Rectangle(5, 30, Width - 400, Height - 270), null, "X", "f");
        myPane.Fill = new Fill(Color.White, Color.Red, 45.0F);
        double Y = double.Parse(s: textBox2.Text);
        double Z = double.Parse(s: textBox3.Text);
        for (Int32 x = 0; x < 100; x++)
        {
            listData.Add(x, Math.Log(Math.Pow(Y, -Math.Sqrt(Math.Abs(x)))) * Math.Pow((Math.Sin(Math.Atan(Z))), 2));
        }
        LineItem DataCurvePop = new LineItem("");
        myPane.AddCurve("данные", listData, Color.Red, rotator.NextSymbol);
        DataCurvePop.Symbol.Fill = new Fill(Color.White);

        myMaster.Add(myPane);
        zdc.AxisChange();
        zdc.Invalidate();
        GraphPane pane = zdc.GraphPane;
        pane.YAxis.Title.Text = "f";
        pane.XAxis.Title.Text = "y";

    }
```

Comment: Полный текст ошибки приложите к вопросу. Могу попытаться угадать, что вы вводите дробные числа с запятой в качестве разделителя, а `double.Parse` ожидает точку. Или наоборот - вы вводите точку, а ожидается запятая. Это решается заменой в строке одного символа на другой.

Comment: Да, и язык программирования в теги добавьте

Comment: ему не нравится каждая строка радиобатона с вот таким кодом 
double Y = double.Parse(s: textBox2.Text);
а также первого батона где я вызывал значение X Y Z

Comment: щас попробовал сделать то что вы мне сказали, все получилось, огромное спасибо!!